# How to add inputs in triangular format in Kotlin?

Tags: arrays, kotlin, data-structures

Please help me to insert (user input) numbers in **triangular format**. below is my code please help me to solve my problem.

```
fun main(){
val n = readLine()!!.toInt()
repeat(n) {
    val x = readLine()!!.toInt()
    val inputs = (1..x).map {
        readLine()!!.split(" ").map { it.toInt() }
    }
    var sum = 0
    for (row in inputs){
        for (column in row){
            sum+=column
        }
    }
    println(sum/2)
    }
}
```

In the above code if I give 3 to x (I can enter 3 rows of numbers with space)
Eg ->

```
2 3 6
4 5 9
2 5 8
```

But I need to insert (user input) numbers in a triangular format like this

```
2 (first row only 1 number) (the code must take only one number in the first row)
4 5 (second row 2 numbers) (the code must take only two numbers in the second row)
2 5 8 (third row 3 numbers) (the code must take only three numbers in the third row)
```

please help me to change my code according to my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I won't write the code for you (is this your homework???), but give you some direction

Firstly it will be easier for you to rationalise if you **separate** the capture of data from the user away from the calculation.

It seems the rules for for your data input are that in any given row number (numbering rows from 0), the number of columns you need are row+1

So think about about something like this

```
var ROWS_TO_READ = 3
initialise a model object - something like List<List<Int>>
for(row in 0 until ROWS_TO_READ) {
  val expectedColumns = row + 1
  val line = readLine()
  splice line expectedColumns number of times, appending into model object
}

perform calculations on the model
```